# redirect vs reverse django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have experienced using reverse within `get_absolute_url` method in the model, but I wish I have an idea about the difference between reverse and redirect, I have tried to search on google about it but there is almost nothing
I don't know what should I write also to convince stack overflow that I don't have any other description

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reverse and redirect have a different meaning. Here is a simple explanation:

`reverse` in Django is used to find the URL of a given resource. Let's say that you have a blog website and from the main page, you want to provide links to your blog posts. You can of course just hard-code `/posts/123/` and just change the ID of your blog post in URL, but that makes it hard to change your URL for the post in the future. That's why Django comes with reverse function. All you need to do is to pass the name of your URL path (defined in your `urlpatterns`) and Django will find for you the correct URL. It is called reverse because it is a reverse process of determining which view should be called for a given URL (which process is called resolving).

Redirects are not specific to Django or any other web frameworks. Redirect means that for a given URL (or action), the user should be instructed to visit a specific URL. This can be done by sending a special redirect request and from there the browser will handle it for the user, so no user action is required in that process. You can use reverse in redirect process to determine the URL that the user should be redirected to.

Comment: i want to thank you a lot for your help, i know it could be strange to ask this question, but i think mu misunderstanding of the actual meaning of these two words made it confusing for me , any way , thank you again

Answer (score 5):

GwynBleidD has given you the answer, but there is a reason why you might be getting confused. The Django `redirect` shortcut accepts arguments in several different forms. One of them is a URLpattern mane, with arguments, that is then passed to reverse to generate the actual URL to redirect to. But that's just a shortcut, to enable a common pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts

Answer (score 3):

here's an example

app/views

```
#imports
def indexView(request):
    ....
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def loginView(request):
    ....
    return redirect('index')

def articleDetailView(request, id):
    ....
    return redirect(reverse('article-comments', kwargs={'id':id})

def articleCommentsView(request, id):
    ....
    return render(request, 'comment_list.html', context)
```

proj/urls

```
#imports
urlpatterns = [
....,
path('', include(app.urls))
]
```

app/urls

```
#imports
urlpatterns = [
....,
path('index/', index, name='index'),
path('login/', loginView, name='login'),
path('article/<int:id>/detail', articleDetailView, name='article-detail'),
path('article/<int:id>/comments/',articleCommentsView,  name='article-comments')
....,
]
```

For loginView *redirect* will return url as-is i.e. 'index' which will be appended to base(project) urlpatterns. Here **redirect(reverse('index'))** will also work since kwargs is None by default for reverse function and '**index**' view doesn't require any kwarg. It returns '/index/' which is passed to redirect(which again will be appended to base urls).

One thing to note is that reverse is used to make complete url - needed for redirect - that is shown in 'articleDetailview'.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic difference between the two is :
 **Redirect** Method will redirect you to a specific route in General.
 **Reverse** Method will return the complete URL to that route as a String.